# NavigationMenu.ImageUrl border style?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a Navigation Menu in .aspx web page.
I set every MenuItem.ImageUrl to a .png Image.
The problem is that the image is shown with a border around of it.
The question is how can I eliminate this border ?

Thankyou very much

Piercarlo

In additions of previous :

[image]

I want to eliminate the border indicated by the arrow, the image was put on the menu Item by the property of menuItem .ImageUrl.
The image is 16 pixel .png with background transparent and without border

I tried without success following:

- css: border:none,
- property of menu:

  ```
   <asp:Menu runat="server">
  <StaticMenuItemStyle  BorderStyle="None" />
  <DynamicMenuItemStyle  BorderStyle="None" />
  ```

I have no idea how do.

Thankyou for helping;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution to my problems with help of javascript following the code:

```
window.onload = GetMenuImage;
function GetMenuImage() {
    var NavMenu = document.getElementById('<%=NavigationMenu.ClientID%>');
    if (NavMenu != null) {
        var Images = NavMenu.getElementsByTagName('img')
        var cont = 0;
        while (cont < Images.length) {
            Images[cont].style.border = 'none';
            Images[cont].style.heigth = '10%';
            Images[cont].style.width = '10%';
            cont++;
        }
    }
```

I hope that this can help some other else

Bye
Piercarlo

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CssClass` property of the `Menu` control to the CSS class for the control where you can then remove the border around the image with `border:none;`